# 'unknown database' error with mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql

I've created a database in my AWS account and I'm trying to connect to it using mysql.connector. If I run:

```
      mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
      host="dbname.xxyyzz.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
      user="user-name",
      password="my_pw"

    )
    print (mydb)
```

I get the expected result:

```
    <mysql.connector.connection.MySQLConnection object at 0x7fbdc89bdf40>
```

If I run the command

```
    mycursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")
```

I get the result

```
    ('information_schema',)
    ('mysql',)
    ('performance_schema',)
    ('sys',)
```

If I try to connect to the database by adding it as a parameter,

```
      mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
      host="dbname.xxyyzz.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
      user="user-name",
      password="my_pw",
      database="test-database"
    )
```

I get the error:

```
    mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1049 (42000): Unknown database
```

I can see it on the AWS UI though:

```
    RDS Databases test-database
```

What am I doing wrong here and why doesn't my database show up?

Comment: Because you don't have a database named `test-database`.

Comment: I suggest connecting using the mysql client and run `SHOW DATABASES;` I reckon you will see a database named "test_database" or some other spelling, not "test-database".

Comment: @BillKarwin if I run the SHOW DATABASES command I get:('information_schema',)
('mysql',)
('performance_schema',)
('sys',)
but my database doesn't show up. I'm seeing it in the AWS UI though.

Comment: i doubt that you are connected tio the rds this would look like https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Python.html

Answer (score 0):

nothing, but if you add `database="test-database"` to the connection string, the database has to be created **before** you try to connect to it

Simply remove the database.

1. connect
2. CREATE the database test-database
3. Send the command ÙSE test-database

The next time you can connect with your code

Comment: This is not the right answer. He ALREADY created the database.

Comment: please read the question again, he hasn't creeted the database as show databases only show the mysql databases and not his own

Comment: If I can only downvote this answer again, read his last sentence. He says “he can see it in [the AWS RDS Console]”. Clearly, he is confused not by the act of creating and using databases, but rather what he is seeing in the RDS Console. What he is seeing in the RDS is the DATABASE IDENTIFIER, which refers to his instance in an AWS managed cluster. Delete this answer and I will add the right answer, since he clearly didn’t mark your answer correct.

Comment: Then you zav n' t understand his question nor did you read the comments , on the connected database is the wanted database not present

Comment: I read everything. The hint is here: "I can see it on the AWS UI though:”. Maybe your English is not proficient. This implies he BELIEVES the database is created already, when it is NOT. I provided the correct answer in these comments. Your answer is bogus.